# Convertir JSON en Clase

Tags: java, servlets, gson

Amigos como podría Convertir un Json en Clase:

Mi Clase es la clase creada a la que debo adaptar el Json que me devuelve autorizationResponse.getResponse()

```
miClase token = gson.fromJson(autorizationResponse.getResponse(),miClase.class);
```

este es el Json que me devuelve y lo debo convertir:

```
{"header":{
    "ecoreTransactionUUID":"7685d60e-0711-45dc-ab02-673761c67666",
    "ecoreTransactionDate":1542377567019,"millis":570
     },
  "order":{"tokenId":"386F86BDE61447A1AF86BDE614D7A1D0",
       "purchaseNumber":"84335","productId":"Whatsapp",
    "amount":210.0,"currency":"PEN", 
        "authorizedAmount":210.0,
        "authorizationCode":"090326",
        "actionCode":"000",
        "traceNumber":"15446",
        "transactionDate":"181116091246",
        "transactionId":"991183200855688"
       },
   "dataMap":{"CURRENCY":"0604",
         "TRANSACTION_DATE":"181116091246",
         "TERMINAL":"00000001",
         "ACTION_CODE":"000",
         "TRACE_NUMBER":"15446",
         "ECI_DESCRIPTION":"Transaccion no autenticada",
         "ECI":"07",
         "CARD":"491914******9067",
         "MERCHANT":"341198210",
         "STATUS":"Authorized",
         "INSTALLMENTS_INFO":"24000000000",
         "ADQUIRENTE":"570002",
         "ACTION_DESCRIPTION":"Aprobado y completado con exito",
         "QUOTA_AMOUNT":"0.00",
         "ID_UNICO":"991183200855688",
         "AMOUNT":"210.00",
         "PROCESS_CODE":"000000",
         "QUOTA_NUMBER":"24",
         "TRANSACTION_ID":"991183200855688",
         "AUTHORIZATION_CODE":"090326",
         "QUOTA_DEFERRED":"0" 
       }
  }
```

Como podría hacer la clase amigos?

Comment: Hay una [herramienta en línea](https://jsonutils.com) que te ayuda a crear la clase a partir del JSON. Funciona para varios lenguajes.

Comment: Gracias hermano

Answer (score 0):

Algunos héroes se han dado la terea de crear librerías capaces de realizar eso en JAVA.

Te comparto el siguiente enlace [JAVAToJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957406/generate-java-class-from-json) donde podes revisar las librerías que te comento. De esa forma cuando recibas el JSON podes convertirlo.

Si nada más necesitas la clase, te quedaría de está forma:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication1; //packege el que estes utilizando

/**
 *
 * @author SourceCode
 */
public class ExampleJsonToJava {
    Header HeaderObject;
    Order OrderObject;
    DataMap DataMapObject;


    // Getter Methods 

    public Header getHeader() {
    return HeaderObject;
    }

    public Order getOrder() {
    return OrderObject;
    }

    public DataMap getDataMap() {
    return DataMapObject;
    }

    // Setter Methods 

    public void setHeader(Header headerObject) {
    this.HeaderObject = headerObject;
    }

    public void setOrder(Order orderObject) {
    this.OrderObject = orderObject;
    }

    public void setDataMap(DataMap dataMapObject) {
    this.DataMapObject = dataMapObject;
    }
}

 class Header {
        private String ecoreTransactionUUID;
        private float ecoreTransactionDate;
        private float millis;


        // Getter Methods 

        public String getEcoreTransactionUUID() {
        return ecoreTransactionUUID;
        }

        public float getEcoreTransactionDate() {
        return ecoreTransactionDate;
        }

        public float getMillis() {
        return millis;
        }

        // Setter Methods 

        public void setEcoreTransactionUUID(String ecoreTransactionUUID) {
        this.ecoreTransactionUUID = ecoreTransactionUUID;
        }

        public void setEcoreTransactionDate(float ecoreTransactionDate) {
        this.ecoreTransactionDate = ecoreTransactionDate;
        }

        public void setMillis(float millis) {
        this.millis = millis;
        }
}

 class Order {
    private String tokenId;
    private String purchaseNumber;
    private String productId;
    private float amount;
    private String currency;
    private float authorizedAmount;
    private String authorizationCode;
    private String actionCode;
    private String traceNumber;
    private String transactionDate;
    private String transactionId;


    // Getter Methods 

    public String getTokenId() {
    return tokenId;
    }

    public String getPurchaseNumber() {
    return purchaseNumber;
    }

    public String getProductId() {
    return productId;
    }

    public float getAmount() {
    return amount;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
    return currency;
    }

    public float getAuthorizedAmount() {
    return authorizedAmount;
    }

    public String getAuthorizationCode() {
    return authorizationCode;
    }

    public String getActionCode() {
    return actionCode;
    }

    public String getTraceNumber() {
    return traceNumber;
    }

    public String getTransactionDate() {
    return transactionDate;
    }

    public String getTransactionId() {
    return transactionId;
    }

    // Setter Methods 

    public void setTokenId(String tokenId) {
    this.tokenId = tokenId;
    }

    public void setPurchaseNumber(String purchaseNumber) {
    this.purchaseNumber = purchaseNumber;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
    this.productId = productId;
    }

    public void setAmount(float amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
    }

    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
    this.currency = currency;
    }

    public void setAuthorizedAmount(float authorizedAmount) {
    this.authorizedAmount = authorizedAmount;
    }

    public void setAuthorizationCode(String authorizationCode) {
    this.authorizationCode = authorizationCode;
    }

    public void setActionCode(String actionCode) {
    this.actionCode = actionCode;
    }

    public void setTraceNumber(String traceNumber) {
    this.traceNumber = traceNumber;
    }

    public void setTransactionDate(String transactionDate) {
    this.transactionDate = transactionDate;
    }

    public void setTransactionId(String transactionId) {
    this.transactionId = transactionId;
    }
}

class DataMap {
    private String CURRENCY;
    private String TRANSACTION_DATE;
    private String TERMINAL;
    private String ACTION_CODE;
    private String TRACE_NUMBER;
    private String ECI_DESCRIPTION;
    private String ECI;
    private String CARD;
    private String MERCHANT;
    private String STATUS;
    private String INSTALLMENTS_INFO;
    private String ADQUIRENTE;
    private String ACTION_DESCRIPTION;
    private String QUOTA_AMOUNT;
    private String ID_UNICO;
    private String AMOUNT;
    private String PROCESS_CODE;
    private String QUOTA_NUMBER;
    private String TRANSACTION_ID;
    private String AUTHORIZATION_CODE;
    private String QUOTA_DEFERRED;


    // Getter Methods 

    public String getCURRENCY() {
    return CURRENCY;
    }

    public String getTRANSACTION_DATE() {
    return TRANSACTION_DATE;
    }

    public String getTERMINAL() {
    return TERMINAL;
    }

    public String getACTION_CODE() {
    return ACTION_CODE;
    }

    public String getTRACE_NUMBER() {
    return TRACE_NUMBER;
    }

    public String getECI_DESCRIPTION() {
    return ECI_DESCRIPTION;
    }

    public String getECI() {
    return ECI;
    }

    public String getCARD() {
    return CARD;
    }

    public String getMERCHANT() {
    return MERCHANT;
    }

    public String getSTATUS() {
    return STATUS;
    }

    public String getINSTALLMENTS_INFO() {
    return INSTALLMENTS_INFO;
    }

    public String getADQUIRENTE() {
    return ADQUIRENTE;
    }

    public String getACTION_DESCRIPTION() {
    return ACTION_DESCRIPTION;
    }

    public String getQUOTA_AMOUNT() {
    return QUOTA_AMOUNT;
    }

    public String getID_UNICO() {
    return ID_UNICO;
    }

    public String getAMOUNT() {
    return AMOUNT;
    }

    public String getPROCESS_CODE() {
    return PROCESS_CODE;
    }

    public String getQUOTA_NUMBER() {
    return QUOTA_NUMBER;
    }

    public String getTRANSACTION_ID() {
    return TRANSACTION_ID;
    }

    public String getAUTHORIZATION_CODE() {
    return AUTHORIZATION_CODE;
    }

    public String getQUOTA_DEFERRED() {
    return QUOTA_DEFERRED;
    }

    // Setter Methods 

    public void setCURRENCY(String CURRENCY) {
    this.CURRENCY = CURRENCY;
    }

    public void setTRANSACTION_DATE(String TRANSACTION_DATE) {
    this.TRANSACTION_DATE = TRANSACTION_DATE;
    }

    public void setTERMINAL(String TERMINAL) {
    this.TERMINAL = TERMINAL;
    }

    public void setACTION_CODE(String ACTION_CODE) {
    this.ACTION_CODE = ACTION_CODE;
    }

    public void setTRACE_NUMBER(String TRACE_NUMBER) {
    this.TRACE_NUMBER = TRACE_NUMBER;
    }

    public void setECI_DESCRIPTION(String ECI_DESCRIPTION) {
    this.ECI_DESCRIPTION = ECI_DESCRIPTION;
    }

    public void setECI(String ECI) {
    this.ECI = ECI;
    }

    public void setCARD(String CARD) {
    this.CARD = CARD;
    }

    public void setMERCHANT(String MERCHANT) {
    this.MERCHANT = MERCHANT;
    }

    public void setSTATUS(String STATUS) {
    this.STATUS = STATUS;
    }

    public void setINSTALLMENTS_INFO(String INSTALLMENTS_INFO) {
    this.INSTALLMENTS_INFO = INSTALLMENTS_INFO;
    }

    public void setADQUIRENTE(String ADQUIRENTE) {
    this.ADQUIRENTE = ADQUIRENTE;
    }

    public void setACTION_DESCRIPTION(String ACTION_DESCRIPTION) {
    this.ACTION_DESCRIPTION = ACTION_DESCRIPTION;
    }

    public void setQUOTA_AMOUNT(String QUOTA_AMOUNT) {
    this.QUOTA_AMOUNT = QUOTA_AMOUNT;
    }

    public void setID_UNICO(String ID_UNICO) {
    this.ID_UNICO = ID_UNICO;
    }

    public void setAMOUNT(String AMOUNT) {
    this.AMOUNT = AMOUNT;
    }

    public void setPROCESS_CODE(String PROCESS_CODE) {
    this.PROCESS_CODE = PROCESS_CODE;
    }

    public void setQUOTA_NUMBER(String QUOTA_NUMBER) {
    this.QUOTA_NUMBER = QUOTA_NUMBER;
    }

    public void setTRANSACTION_ID(String TRANSACTION_ID) {
    this.TRANSACTION_ID = TRANSACTION_ID;
    }

    public void setAUTHORIZATION_CODE(String AUTHORIZATION_CODE) {
    this.AUTHORIZATION_CODE = AUTHORIZATION_CODE;
    }

    public void setQUOTA_DEFERRED(String QUOTA_DEFERRED) {
    this.QUOTA_DEFERRED = QUOTA_DEFERRED;
    }
}
```

Suerte...

Comment: Amigo solo tengo que crear esa clase que me muestras o muy aparte de esa que me muestras tengo que crear para header, order y datamap?, me esta mostrando error, o faltara una libreria?

Comment: Ya te la edite, suponía necesitabas una guía no que las ibas a copiar :D. Ahora sí, solo copia y pega. Suerte.

Comment: Gracias amigo, me sirvió